# Build your own Angular for Angular 14

Tags: angular

Years ago, when I learn AngularJS, the best resource I found was the book [Build your own Angular](https://github.com/teropa/build-your-own-angularjs)

Does anyone know if there is something equivalent for the new Angular? Something that explains not only how to use it, but also its inner workings.